# flex google multiple markers

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have made multiple markers via javascript, but trying to do the same in actionscript is proving to be quite challenging.

I am using googles directions to retrieve a LatLng to add markers, but it's only returning one marker. Either the first or the second.

Within my init function are the markers address array and call to return LatLng from directions. Basically placing the start and end as the same to place the marker.

```
markers = ['11030 Hartsook st, North Hollywood, CA','15713 Ventura blvd, Encino, CA'];
for (var i:Number = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
from.text=markers[i];
textInput.text=markers[i];
processForm(evt);
}

private function processForm(event:Event):void {
var directions:Directions = new Directions();
directions.addEventListener(DirectionsEvent.DIRECTIONS_SUCCESS, onDirectionsSuccess);
directions.addEventListener(DirectionsEvent.DIRECTIONS_FAILURE, onDirectionsFail);
directions.load("from: " + from.text + " to: " + textInput.text);
}

private function onDirectionsSuccess(event:DirectionsEvent):void{
            googleMap.clearOverlays();
            directionsSteps.removeAll();

            directions = event.directions;
            var directionsPolyline:IPolyline = directions.createPolyline();
            googleMap.addOverlay(directionsPolyline);

            /*************************************
             * zoomout after retrieving directions
             * ***********************************/
            var directionsBounds:LatLngBounds = directionsPolyline.getLatLngBounds();
            googleMap.setCenter(directionsBounds.getCenter());
            googleMap.setZoom(googleMap.getBoundsZoomLevel(directionsBounds));

            /*************************************
             * create markers
             * ***********************************/             
            startLatLng = directions.getRoute(0).getStep(0).latLng;
            var endLatLng:LatLng = directions.getRoute(directions.numRoutes-1).endLatLng;
            googleMap.addOverlay(new Marker(startLatLng));
            googleMap.addOverlay(new Marker(endLatLng));
            myMarkers.push(new Marker(startLatLng));
            mgr.addMarkers(myMarkers, myMarkers.length);
            mgr.refresh();

            /*************************************
             * create steps
             * ***********************************/ 
            for (var r:Number = 0 ; r < directions.numRoutes; r++ ) {
                var route:Route = directions.getRoute(r);

                for (var s:Number = 0 ; s < route.numSteps; s++ ) {
                    var step:Step = route.getStep(s);
                    directionsSteps.addItem(step);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: why is it only returning the first marker or the last? Why not both?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to abandon the old code and use httpservice to retrieve the lat, lng for each address:

```
            private function makeMarkers():void {
            for (var x:Number= 0; x < markers.length; x++) {
                loadMyXml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+markers[x]+"&sensor=false");
            }
        }

        private function loadMyXml(src:String):void {
            httpService.url = src;
            httpService.send();
        }


            public function httpService_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            covToXML = new XML(event.result);
            xmlToList = new XMLList(covToXML);
            listToCol = new XMLListCollection(xmlToList);
            someLat = Number(listToCol.children().child("geometry").child("location").child("lat").text());
            someLng = Number(listToCol.children().child("geometry").child("location").child("lng").text());
            someAddress = String(listToCol.children().child("formatted_address").text());

            // Alert.show(someLat +", "+ someLng + someAddress);
            var someMarker:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(someLat , someLng), new MarkerOptions({tooltip:someAddress, hasShadow: true}));
            //googleMap.addOverlay(someMarker);
            myMarkers.push(someMarker);
            mgr.addMarkers(myMarkers, 1);
            mgr.refresh();
            markerSetBounds(someLat , someLng);
        }
```

Now, I am having issues with the setting the bounds. The map keeps centering on the initial center, before the markers where added.

Getting ready to post another question.